# How to size an image in hp

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to resize an image in this link
I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
<a  href="<?php echo esc_url( $image_popup_url ); ?>" class="image-popup"><?php echo 'height="130" width="150"'. the_post_thumbnail( 'colormag-featured-image' ); ?></a>
```

Comment: So what exactly did you think would outputting `height="130" width="150"` as the _text content of a link_ achieve in that regard?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_image_size( 'colormag-featured-image', 150, 130, true );` in your `functions.php` files after setup theme function.

Then Use code like this -

```
<a  href="<?php echo esc_url( $image_popup_url ); ?>" class="image-popup"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'colormag-featured-image' ); ?></a>
```

It will work.